# Use of undeclared identifier GluBuildMipMaps (emscripten)

Tags: c++, opengl, webgl, sdl, emscripten

I've created an OpenGL program using SDL. I've tried it to compile to HTML5+JS using emscripten, but I get this error:

[image: emscripten error]

I can't understand, why I get this error. GluBuildMipMaps is defined in `glu.h`: https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/master/system/include/GL/glu.h

The glm errors are also confusing, because I've copied the glm library to the `glm` directory, and it is included where I use it.

---

**Edit**

The error message in plain text:

```
D:\proj\e_bead>emcc main.cpp MyApp.cpp ObjParser_OGL3.cpp -s FULL_ES2=1 -O3 --me
mory-init-file 0
In file included from MyApp.cpp:2:
./GLUtils.hpp:148:2: error: use of undeclared identifier 'gluBuild2DMipmaps'
        gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, loaded_img->w, loaded_i...
        ^
MyApp.cpp:194:25: error: no matching function for call to 'translate'
  ...spaceShipTransform = glm::translate<float>(randnum, randnum, randnum);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl:40:35: note: candidate function template not
      viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate
                                         ^
./glm/gtx/transform.inl:36:35: note: candidate function template not viable:
      requires single argument 'v', but 3 arguments were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate(
                                         ^
MyApp.cpp:199:25: error: no matching function for call to 'translate'
  ...spaceShipTransform = glm::translate<float>(randnum, randnum, randnum);
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl:40:35: note: candidate function template not
      viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate
                                         ^
./glm/gtx/transform.inl:36:35: note: candidate function template not viable:
      requires single argument 'v', but 3 arguments were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate(
                                         ^
MyApp.cpp:234:9: error: no matching function for call to 'translate'
        mvp *= glm::translate(0.0f, 5.0f, 0.0f);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./glm/gtc/matrix_transform.inl:40:35: note: candidate function template not
      viable: requires 2 arguments, but 3 were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate
                                         ^
./glm/gtx/transform.inl:36:35: note: candidate function template not viable:
      requires single argument 'v', but 3 arguments were provided
        GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tmat4x4<T, P> translate(
                                         ^
4 errors generated.
ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

---

**Edit2**

I've copied the `glm` library into the glm directory, and include it with this code:

```
// GLM
#include "glm/glm.hpp"
#include "glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp"
#include "glm/gtx/transform2.hpp"
```

The texture loading code, where `gluBuild2DMipmaps` is called:

```
GLuint TextureFromFile(const char* filename)
{
    SDL_Surface* loaded_img = IMG_Load(filename);  

    int img_mode = 0;

    if ( loaded_img == 0 )
    {
        std::cout << "[TextureFromFile] Error when loading image: " << filename << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    #if SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_LIL_ENDIAN
        if ( loaded_img->format->BytesPerPixel == 4 )
            img_mode = GL_BGRA;
        else
            img_mode = GL_BGR;
    #else
        if ( loaded_img->format->BytesPerPixel == 4 )
            img_mode = GL_RGBA;
        else
            img_mode = GL_RGB;
    #endif

    GLuint tex;
    glGenTextures(1, &tex);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
    gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, loaded_img->w, loaded_img->h, img_mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, loaded_img->pixels);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    SDL_FreeSurface( loaded_img );

    return tex;
}
```

---

**Edit3**

I've edited `GLUtils.hpp` according to `Robert Rouhani`'s answer, and now I don't get compile error at this line:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
//gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGB, loaded_img->w, loaded_img->h, img_mode, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, loaded_img->pixels);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
    0,
    GL_RGB,
    loaded_img->w,
    loaded_img->h,
    0,
    img_mode,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
    loaded_img->pixels);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // /!\ Allocate the mipmaps /!\
```

Comment: It's more usual to post the text of the errors you get as text rather than a screen shot, both to make it easier to read now and easier to search for later. Is it ok if you do that?

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with emscripten, but from some searching it looks like your option of `FULL_ES2=1` means that you get the whole OpenGL ES 2.0 API. I'd guess that means that the only include directory you get is [GLES2](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include/GLES2) instead of [GL](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/tree/master/system/include/GL), the folder containing the `glu.h` that you linked to.

GLU is almost 20 years old now, and only worked up to OpenGL 1.3 (released in 2001). This means you can't use it with ES 2.0. What you want instead is [`glGenerateMipmap`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glGenerateMipmap.xhtml) with [`glHint`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/html/glHint.xhtml) and the `GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP_HINT` option for it. An example:

```
//Create the mipmapped texture
glGenTextures(1, &ColorbufferName);
glBindTexture(ColorbufferName);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 512, 512, 0, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D); // /!\ Allocate the mipmaps /!\
```

Taken from [this article](http://www.g-truc.net/post-0256.html).

As for the glm errors, it looks like it's finding glm properly, it just doesn't like the way you're using it (and only for the `translate` function). Could you post the relevant lines from MyApp.cpp (the line with the error and a few above and below it for context)?

Other people have gotten glm to work with emscripten, perhaps this mailing list post would be helpful to you: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/emscripten-discuss/b6DY3GCDlug

---

**EDIT**: For the glm errors

You're simply using the wrong includes.

- [glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00171.html) only includes one version of `glm::transform` that takes in a matrix and a vertex and returns the transformed matrix.
- [glm/gtx/transform2.hpp](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.6/api/a00234.html) doesn't contain any version of `glm::translate`

**What you want is [glm/gtx/transform.hpp](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00206.html#ga353b66810f6788c6486197cb6a30248c)**

Comment: I don't believe this code sequence will work. `glGenerateMipmap()` generates mipmaps based on the current data in the base texture level. Since you just called `glTexImage2D()` with `NULL` for the data, there is no texture data, and no mipmaps will be generated.

Comment: @RetoKoradi The code was taken exactly from the article (written by author of glm), and is designed to explain how/where `glGenerateMipmap` is called, not for copy/pasting.

Still, passing `NULL` for data is [considered valid by the spec](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml#notes). It allocates enough memory for the described texture, so your texture will be black or garbage data. Additionally, `NULL` or `0` is valid and will copy pixels if anything is bound to `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER`, as `data` is an offset into the buffer. You'll still get a mipmap.

Comment: Sure you can call `glTexImage2D()` with `NULL` for the data, that's very commonly used. But you need to call `glGenerateMipmap()` **after** you fill it with data. Just because the code is on the internet doesn't make it correct.

Comment: Again, the glTexImage2D call is not the point of the snippet and this is just a nitpick. Test it out on your machine if you want, I'm pretty sure you're going to get a black texture with mipmaps on nvidia and Intel cards and some sort of noisy texture on AMD with mipmaps. The memory is allocated, OpenGL doesn't care if it's garbage data or some texture.

Comment: It's also from g-truc, who wrote glm and reads through and writes a review on every new OpenGL spec. I'd trust his OpenGL code over most other people on the planet.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I edited the question, with more details. The glGenerateMipmap error is solved, only the glm errors remained

Comment: I still get the error for some reason: `MyApp.cpp:194:25: error: no matching function for call to 'translate': glm::translate<float>(randnum, randnum, randnum);`

Comment: without your code, I can only guess that `randnum` isn't a float? the `<float>` should be unnecessary, perhaps try casting it to a float earlier or changing the call to `glm::translate((float)randnum, (float)randnum, (float)randnum);`?